# CSS Grid span more rows on content overflow?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a special css grid layout that is based on completely square grid boxes that are defined like this:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(5, minmax(200px, 20vw));
grid-auto-rows: minmax(200px, 20vw);

grid-template-areas:                        
"branding       nav         nav             .                   meta" 
".              title       title           featured-image      ."
".              primary     primary         featured-image      ."
".              secondary   secondary       featured-image      ."
".              footer      footer          .                   .";
```

problem is that I need to have a content area within this grid that is flexible. By default it spans 2 columns and 2 rows. The content area is outlined in red:

[image]

I would like the layout to make it possible for the content area to span for example 2 columns and 4 rows for example. Basically 2-n rows based on the content.

Is there any smart way of doing this?

Comment: It is but not by using the `template areas` you have in place. If you don't define those you can make elements span any rows/columns you want.

Comment: Ok, so how do I do that dynamically based on the content?

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar for a HomePage, but using JavaScript not just CSS grid:
A card grid ocupying 2 rows only if the contents overflow the container.

```
static expandIfActive(card){
    const content = card.querySelector('.content')
    const body = card.querySelector('.card-body')
    return body.clientHeight - options.clientHeight - (#margins and paddings)  == 0
}
```

If the content matches the heigth of the container means it's overflowing, so I add the property `grid-row: span 2`